# Can this MDX be optimized?

Tags: mdx

I have a MDX query as below:

```sql
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts] AS [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]/SUM({[Contract].[Product Group].&[P1], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P2], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P3]}, [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR])
SELECT
    NON EMPTY
    {
        [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal USD],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal Local Currency],
        [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    { (
        [Contract].[Product Group].ALLMEMBERS,
        [Dates].[YearMonth].ALLMEMBERS
    ) } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    { (
        STRTOSET(@ContractProductGroup, CONSTRAINED),
        STRTOSET(@DatesYearMonth, CONSTRAINED)
    ) } ON 0
    FROM [Assets]
)
WHERE
{
    { [Contract].[Unit].&[U1], [Contract].[Unit].&[U2], [Contract].[Unit].&[U3] },
    [Assets Cont].[Contract Status].&[C1]
}
```

Can this be optimized?

I know that you cannot run it on your machines, but I want to know is there something in this query that is not a good practice or it could be done better.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make your custom measure more sparse by introducing some nulls.
Also on your `ON ROWS` why not just use a normal cross-join.
Try the `.MEMBERS`rather than the `.ALLMEMBERS` function.
You could try creating a custom set in the `WITH` clause: `[nonEmpSet]`
Also I have changed the curly braces in your `WHERE` clause to tuple braces as this is more standard.

```
WITH 
  SET [nonEmpSet] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      {
        [Contract].[Product Group].MEMBERS * [Dates].[YearMonth].MEMBERS
      },
     ,[Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Accounts NEW] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Contract].[Product Group].&[P1]
       ,[Contract].[Product Group].&[P2]
       ,[Contract].[Product Group].&[P3]
      }
     ,[Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Accounts NEW] = 0
     ,null
     ,
      [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR] / [Measures].[Accounts NEW]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]
     ,[Measures].[SUM Principal USD]
     ,[Measures].[SUM Principal Local Currency]
     ,[Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [nonEmpSet] ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      (
        StrToSet
        (@ContractProductGroup
         ,CONSTRAINED
        )
       ,StrToSet
        (@DatesYearMonth
         ,CONSTRAINED
        )
      )
    } ON 0
  FROM [Assets]
)
WHERE 
  (
    {
      [Contract].[Unit].&[U1]
     ,[Contract].[Unit].&[U2]
     ,[Contract].[Unit].&[U3]
    }
   ,[Assets Cont].[Contract Status].&[C1]
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I just did this, but unfortunately didn't notice any improvements in time.

Comment: @irusul - let me edit my script as I think I can see a problem - your `ON ROWS` code is strange - why not just do a normal cross join ?

Comment: It is another way for cross join, anyway the performance is the same.

Comment: Do you have calculated members in the Contract and Dates dimensions? Why do you use `AllMembers` function?

Comment: I need a split by date and contract.

Comment: I just mean use `.members` rather than `.allmembers`. Although this probably won't make a speed difference

Comment: I think a custom set might help using `nonempty` - let me edit again.

Answer (score 0):

If not an issue, create a cube level member as below:

```
CREATE
MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts] AS NULL;

SCOPE(
{
    { [Contract].[Unit].&[U1], [Contract].[Unit].&[U2], [Contract].[Unit].&[U3] },
    [Assets Cont].[Contract Status].&[C1]
});

[Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts] =
Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]
/
SUM({[Contract].[Product Group].&[P1], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P2], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P3]}, [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]);

END SCOPE;
```

Also in your query use the `NonEmpty()` function to get rid of unnecessary crossjoins.

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY
    {
        [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal USD],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal Local Currency],
        [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    NonEmpty(
        [Contract].[Product Group].ALLMEMBERS,
        [Dates].[YearMonth].ALLMEMBERS
    ) ON ROWS
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    { (
        STRTOSET(@ContractProductGroup, CONSTRAINED),
        STRTOSET(@DatesYearMonth, CONSTRAINED)
    ) } ON 0
    FROM [Assets]
)
```

**EDIT - WHERE clause instead of sub select**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts] AS 
[Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]
/
SUM({[Contract].[Product Group].&[P1], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P2], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P3]}, [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR])

SELECT
    NON EMPTY
    {
        [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal USD],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal Local Currency],
        [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    { (
        [Contract].[Product Group].ALLMEMBERS,
        [Dates].[YearMonth].ALLMEMBERS
    ) } ON ROWS

    FROM [Assets]
WHERE
{
    { [Contract].[Unit].&[U1], [Contract].[Unit].&[U2], [Contract].[Unit].&[U3] },
    [Assets Cont].[Contract Status].&[C1],
    STRTOSET(@ContractProductGroup, CONSTRAINED),
    STRTOSET(@DatesYearMonth, CONSTRAINED)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts] AS 
[Measures].[SUM Principal EUR]
/
SUM({[Contract].[Product Group].&[P1], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P2], [Contract].[Product Group].&[P3]}, [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR])

SELECT
    NON EMPTY
    {
        [Measures].[SUM Principal EUR],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal USD],
        [Measures].[SUM Principal Local Currency],
        [Measures].[Percentage of All Accounts]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    { (
       STRTOSET(@ContractProductGroup, CONSTRAINED),
       STRTOSET(@DatesYearMonth, CONSTRAINED)
    ) } ON ROWS

    FROM [Assets]
WHERE
{
    { [Contract].[Unit].&[U1], [Contract].[Unit].&[U2], [Contract].[Unit].&[U3] },
    [Assets Cont].[Contract Status].&[C1]
}
```

Comment: NONEMPTY on rows didn't help. I cannot create cube level member, I have many more members (not shown here).

Comment: @irusul How about getting rid of `NON EMPTY` completely from both the axes??

Comment: I cannot put the same hierarchy in two dimensions. I already have Dates and Contracts on Rows, putting it on where is impossible.

Comment: @irusul Ok, I wasn't aware of that. Check Edit 2